# Overflow of sidebar with Twitter Bootstrap Affix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-position, sticky, affix

I'm trying to use the affix plugin by twitter bootstrap but I can't figure out how to constrain it within the parent container, i've created the following example to show my problem:

Problem demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/DvcRXkeFZa

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 column">
            <ul id="sidebar" class="well nav nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="130">
                <li><a href="#software"><b>Software</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#benefits">Benefits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#costs">Costs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 column">
            <h1>Blah, blah, blah</h1>
            <hr>
            <a class="anchor3" id="top" name="software"></a>
            <p>
             content here that scrolls...
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see when you scroll it overflows out of the sidebar, it also doesn't affix to the bottom of the page when it reaches the bottom.

Comment: down since link is removed/redirects to fansite

Comment: down since link is removed/redirects to fansite

Comment: A perfect example of why external links aren't a good idea, and the code should always be in the question.

Answer (score 24):

From the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#affix)..

> Heads up! You must manage the position of a pinned element and the
>   behavior of its immediate parent. Position is controlled by affix,
>   affix-top, and affix-bottom. Remember to check for a potentially
>   collapsed parent when the affix kicks in as it's removing content from
>   the normal flow of the page.

So you need some CSS for `affix` to set the width for the element when it becomes fixed. Such as:

```
#sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width:225px;
  }
```

Demo on Bootply: http://bootply.com/73864

Related answers on Bootstrap affix:
[How to create a sticky left sidebar menu using bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681895/how-to-create-a-sticky-left-sidebar-menu-using-bootstrap-3/21497753#21497753)
[Twitter-bootstrap 3 affixed sidebar overlapping content when window resized and also footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028843/twitter-bootstrap-3-affixed-sidebar-overlapping-content-when-window-resized-and/21029328#21029328)

Comment: But how would the width work given that bootstrap is supposed to be responsive? Setting it to inherit gives it a width of 20% like the span and 100% makes it cover the whole page?

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop You have to explicitly handle that in your css w/ media queries, by defining the width of the affixed attribute at each breakpoint. Not ideal. I wish you could affix standard columns like this `<div class="col-md-3 affix">` and have it automagically affix to whatever size 3 columns represents in any viewport size.

Comment: Or only apply the affix responsively using media queries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21029328/171456

Answer (score 3):

In an answer to @FreezeDriedPop I found this to work for me:

```
var navbw = $('#sidebar').width()-7;
$('header').append('<style id="addedCSS" type="text/css">#sidebar.affix {width:'+navbw+'px;}</style>');
```

Comment: Also add this to be able to keep the correct size on resize of the window!
`$( window ).resize(function() {
var navbw = $('#sidebar').width();
  $('header').append('<style id="addedCSS" type="text/css">#sidebar.affix {width:'+navbw+'px;}</style>');
});`
@kurt @Freeze @Skelly