# how to stick left and right side panel in bootstrap

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">

                        </aside><aside id="edd_categories_tags_widget-3" class="widget widget_edd_categories_tags_widget">
                        <h1 class="widget-title section-title"><span>Categories</span></h1>
                        <ul class="edd-taxonomy-widget">
                            <li >Breakfast</li>
                            <li >Soups</li>
                            <li >Main Course</li>
                            <li >Starters</li>
                            <li >Salads</li>
                        </ul>
                        </aside></div>
                </div>
```

I want to stick left side menu in the bootstrap page. Now it's going under navigation bar.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfrBa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer of ZimSystem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681895/how-to-create-a-sticky-left-sidebar-menu-using-bootstrap-3)

The trick is using the affix component along with some CSS to position it:

```
 #sidebar.affix-top {
    position: static;
    margin-top:30px;
    width:228px;
  }

  #sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top:70px;
    width:228px;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I used this css but the side menu is going to under footer it is not sticked correctly.